# Fixed point subspaces $V^B$ and $V^G$ for a Borel subgroup $B\subset G$ coincide

Tags: algebraic-geometry, representation-theory, algebraic-groups

Assume that $G$ is a linear algebraic group, and let $B \subset G$ a Borel subgroup of it. Let $(V,\rho)$ a rational $G$-module. Define $$V^G := \{ v \in V \mid g \cdot v = v \quad \forall g \in G \}$$ prove that $V^B = V^G$.

**My attempt** Obviously $V^G \subset V^B$ because $B \subset G$. My strategy is to find a way to prove (if it is true!) that the action $G \to GL_n(V)$ can be restarted to an action $G\to GL_n(V^B)$. **Assuming** that true, then by hypothesis the morphism factor through the quotient $G/B$ which is a projective variety and whose image is still a closed subset of $GL_n(V^B)$, hence affine and hence the image is a finite set of points (because is proper) and hence by connectedness it's the identity. Hence $V^B$ is $G$-stable and hence $V^B \subset V^G$. The point is that I'm not able to prove that I can restrict the action to $V^B$. I hope the rest of the reasoning is clear and correct.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I can see, your reasoning is fine, and you don't even need an action of $G$ on $V^B$: It suffices to pick some $v\in V^B$ and to consider the map $G\to V$ given by $g\mapsto g.v$. Since $v\in V^B$, this map factors through $G/B\to V$, and your arguments show that it must be constant.

Comment: Dear Hanno, how can you prove that the map $G \to V$ $g \mapsto g.v$ is indeed a morphism? because I need that to let my machinery works. By def. of rational module the assignment $g \to \rho_g \in GL_n(V)$ is a morphism

Comment: Dear Luigi! I don't know your precise definitions, but for fixed $v\in V$ the map $\text{GL}_n(V)\to V$, $\phi\mapsto \phi(v)$ should be a morphism.